# jwplayer - receives a "Error loading playlist: Error loading file"

Tags: rss, jwplayer

I receive "Error loading playlist: Error loading file"

The html page...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="/Players/jwplayer6.8.js"></script>
    <script src="/Players/jwplayer.html5.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divPlayer"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer('divPlayer').setup({
                playlist: 'http://media.howdoyouguru.com/guru/130438044361506556/2c4f8cc1-6142-441a-85e3-393f8614d4b3.xml',
                width: 640,
                height: 380
            })
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The rss file...

```
<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:jwplayer="http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/FlashFormats" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>GURU Online Playlist</title>
        <item>
            <title>Custom Audio 10 seconds past Video</title>
            <jwplayer:source file="http://media.howdoyouguru.com/guru/130438044361506556/ab66f56f-f43c-4a7e-b858-9c616c592044.mp4"/>
            <jwplayer:image url="http://media.howdoyouguru.com/guru/130438044361506556/52e36daf-b731-4607-bead-24354bd851c8.jpg"/>
       </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I have gone out to each file to make sure it exists and the mp4 file will play if type in the url for the file.

The url is test.howdoyouguru.com/test.html

Thanks for the help.
Gary

Comment: Your link is down.


Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link test.howdoyouguru.com/test.html works.
when trying loading the xml file this error prevent jwplayer loading the xml file

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://media.howdoyouguru.com/guru/130438044361506556/2c4f8cc1-6142-441a-85e3-393f8614d4b3.xml.
 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
 Origin 'http://test.howdoyouguru.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to your xml and then it will work

**EDIT**

How to enable CORS

http://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html

Comment: I have set the crossdomain.xml to <allow-access-from domain="*"/>. If I still need the header do you have an example? Thanks